# IMessageFilter for wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, imessagefilter

I couldn't find anything about it online, so is there an interface similar to IMessageFilter for wpf, or a way of using this interface with a wpf window?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. There is no equivalent of IMessageFilter in WPF. As per [Josh Smith](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/13af970f-981f-4ce1-ac6c-9dd9f2c5d2ce/message-filters-in-wpf-) -

> There is no equivalent of IMessageFilter in WPF.  But you might be
>   able to devise some scheme where your app's main window's wndproc is
>   subclassed and you filter on the power-awareness messages.  When they
>   pass through, notify some other class which the entire application can
>   then listen to via Observer pattern.