# WPF Intercept global mouse movements (like using IMessageFilter in Windows Form)

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, imessagefilter

I'm converting a `UserControl` from **Windows Form** to **WPF**, Here is my **Windows Form** working code:

```
GlobalMouseHandler mouseHandler = new GlobalMouseHandler();
mouseHandler.MouseMove += OnGlobalMouseMove;
mouseHandler.MouseButtonUp += OnGlobalMouseButtonUp;

public class GlobalMouseHandler : IMessageFilter, IDisposable
{
    public event MouseMovedEvent MouseMove;
    public event MouseButtonUpEvent MouseButtonUp;

    public GlobalMouseHandler(){
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                MouseMove?.Invoke();
                break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                MouseButtonUp?.Invoke();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I used `IMessageFilter` to get the mouse move and mouse up events in my application and attach to them.

Now, I know that [IMessageFilter is not available in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511461/2965109), but is there a simple way to record these simple mouse events in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle messages similar way (mouse move for example):

Xaml:

```
<Window ... Loaded="Window_OnLoaded">
    ...
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
    using System.Windows.Interop;

    ...

    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

    private void Window_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)?.AddHook(this.WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                // MouseMove?.Invoke();
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Of course, if you don't want to do it in native WPF manner (left button up for example):

```
<Window ... PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Window_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    ...
</Window>

private void Window_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Handled = true if you want to prevent following MouseLeftButtonUp event processing
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I have a problem: I'm not loading a window, but a generic UserControl (System.Windows.Controls) so I cannot pass a Window to the WindowInteropHelper constructor. Is there a way to use "current main window" or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you can try `Window.GetWindow(this)` from inside your `UserControl`